# Increment ID in DerbyDB

Tags: mysql, javafx, derby

```
CREATE TABLE GROUPS
(GROUP_ID INT NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY 
(START WITH 100, INCREMENT BY 1), ADDRESS VARCHAR(100), PHONE VARCHAR(15));
```

I am using the above line to create a Table in JavaFX but every time I close out of the application after entering new data the sequence numbering for the ID jumps ahead by 100 so if I enter 3 records with the first sign on my sequence is 100 101 102 close the program and reopen and enter 3 more records the sequence is 200 201 202 
What variable is storing this value and why does it increment by 100 with each sign on? Or How do I correct this problem?
the database is DerbyDB and it is Embedded with the application in a folder on C drive, ID is set as the Primary Key

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31804210/derby-auto-increment-by-100-when-specified-as-1

Answer (score 1):

@James_Duh

How are you closing the database
I have an idea you might be missing this line of code

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:;shutdown=true")
```

hope this helps
@Strawberry nice edit where is the answer